# magento front page 404 error

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

my front page cannot be found now.
First I change my catalog.xml file and refresh my cache then my front page is not working.
Page cannot be found!! But back-end is working.

My version is 1.6.2.0.

Comment: Undo the changes you made, they obviously did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your default CMS page in the admin.  Go to `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages` and ensure that the `CMS Home Page` exists and is allowed in your current Store View.